# Using Url.Action and route data in Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using `Url.Action` to generate the request link in an AJAX call. Then I manually append the `Id` to it.

```
$('#form #field').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
        var val = this.value;
        var url = '@(Url.Action("action", "control"))' + '/' + val;
        $("#form").load(url);
    }
});
```

The problem is that each `Url.Action` seems to keep the last query strings. So if I call the function with the value 1, the second time that I call it `url` is:

```
var url = '/control/action/1' + '/' + val;
```

What's the right way to call `Url.Action` in JavaScript code?

Comment: you always can place your js on Layout or some other View =) You can even place it on partial View, but it's bad practice

Answer (score 0):

`var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {Area = "", Id = val})'`

Comment: It would be nice if you would explain the code and how it answers the question. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and write answers that could really help.

Comment: Having a null area doesn't help, and `val` is a JS variable, I can't assign it like that.